# GCC v12.1 warning about serial compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc-warning, gcc12

I have upgraded my whole [*arch linux*](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/gcc/) system today (12<sup>th</sup> May, 2022). `gcc` was also upgraded from `v11.2` to **`v12.1`**. I tried compiling some of my programs with `g++` (part of `gcc` compiler collection) by the following command:

```bash
g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -Os -Ofast -Og -s -march=native -flto -funroll-all-loops -std=c++20 main.cc -o ./main
```

The program compiled perfectly and ran as excepted without any errors, but I got a warning:

```bash
lto-wrapper: warning: using serial compilation of 2 LTRANS jobs
```

But, when the same program was compiled using `v11.2` it *produces zero number of errors and warnings*.

My Questions:

- What is the meaning of this warning?
- How can I fix this?
- Is this warning occurred due to upgrading `gcc` version to `v12.1`

Here's the `g++` configuration on my machine:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --enable-link-serialization=1
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently that is a recent change in the `-flto` option. After some searching, I was able to find [this mail conversation](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg258441.html):

> Likewise if people just use -flto and auto-detection
> finds nothing:
>
> warning: using serial compilation of N LTRANS jobs
> note: refer to http://.... for how to use parallel compile
>
> [...]
>
> That is, teach users rather than second-guessing and eventually
> blowing things up.  IMHO only the jobserver mode is safe to
> automatically use.

So this is about using the `-flto` options correctly. I could not manage to easily get a GCC 12 on my system and thus could not try it myself, but you can try `-flto=1` or `-flto=auto` to get rid of the warning.

Anyway it seems that this warning is rather harmless. It just tells you that GCC uses 2 threads in parallel to do the link time optimization.

The exact semantics and effects of the `-flto` is (together with the other optimization options) described in detail in the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). By the way you should not spam optimization options like you do in your command line. For example specifying multiple `-O...` options will only have the effect of the last one of them. Unless you know exactly what you are doing **and have carefully read the manual**, just stick to use `-O3` and you will be fine.

Comment: I know its kinda late to ask, but what were the variations you did on the google search?

Comment: I don't remember the exact google search term, but it took me several attempts to find that mail archive with google search. Maybe it's better to remove that sentence from the answer...

Comment: Here is another thread discussing the issue as of late April 2023, evidently auto and =N options are not yet fixing the warning https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/1284